# mysql query from 4 tables to include empty records (solved: nested select within left join)

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems getting this MySql query to work. Basically we have the tables:
"item" (with products)
"flags" (we use these to mark flag specific products)
"itemflagassign" (that says which items have which flags)
"customerorder" and
"customerorderpos" (with the items ordered).

Now I've created this query which perfectly shows total sales per flag:

```
SELECT t4.flagid, 
t4.name, 
COUNT(*) AS count_totalorders, 
SUM(t1.quantity_ordered - t1.quantity_cancelled) AS quantity_ordered, 
SUM(t1.itemtotal) AS item_total, 
SUM(t1.itemtotal - (quantity_ordered * t1.purchase_price)) AS item_earningstotal, 
((SUM(t1.itemtotal) / SUM(quantity_ordered * t1.purchase_price)) * 100) AS    item_calculationtotal 
FROM customerorderpos t1, customerorder t2, itemflagassign t3, flag t4
WHERE t2.customerorderid=t1.customerorderid and t2.datetime >= 1388534400 and t2.status_cancelled = 0 and t3.itemid=t1.itemid and     t4.flagid=t3.flagid
GROUP BY t4.flagid
```

But I want to include the flags *that have no sales*. That means they exist in the flag and the itemflagassign tables, but there are no corresponding records in customerorder or customerorderpos. 
So I need *either* the records with customer orders within the date range specified *or* the ones with no customer order records at all.
I've tried all day re-writing with left joins but the query just ends up running forever (these are big tables, the orderpos has 100000+ records).

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select YourColumns ...
from itemflagassign t3
inner join flag t4 on t4.flagid = t3.flagid
left join customerorderpos t1 on t3.itemid = t1.itemid
left join customerorder t2 on t2.customerorderid = t1.customerorderid
    and t2.datetime >= 1388534400
    and t2.status_cancelled = 0
group by ...
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! The query just runs and runs forever though (I tried it just "select t3.itemid", no other columns, but it won't load)

Answer (score 0):

solved it!
Every join I tried just made the query run forever... What works perfectly though is putting a nested SELECT within a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t2.flagid, 
t2.name, 
COUNT(distinct t3.customerorderid) AS count_totalorders,
SUM(t3.quantity_ordered - t3.quantity_cancelled) AS quantity_ordered, 
SUM(t3.itemtotal) AS item_total, 
SUM(t3.itemtotal - (quantity_ordered * t3.purchase_price)) AS item_earningstotal,  
((SUM(t3.itemtotal) / SUM(quantity_ordered * t3.purchase_price)) * 100) AS item_calculationtotal 
FROM itemflagassign t1
JOIN flag t2 on t2.flagid=t1.flagid
LEFT JOIN (select tt2.customerorderid, itemid, quantity_ordered, quantity_cancelled, itemtotal, purchase_price from customerorderpos tt1, customerorder tt2 where tt1.customerorderid=tt2.customerorderid and tt2.datetime >= MY_DATE_FROM and tt2.datetime <= MY_DATE_TO and tt2.status_cancelled = 0) t3 on t3.itemid=t1.itemid
GROUP BY t2.flagid
```